# How to get a list of all the classes in one .py file?

Tags: python

```
mm.py

class A():
    def __init__(self):
           pass
class B():
    def __int__(slef):
           pass
```

How can I generate a list of all the classes in mm.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `inspect`:

```
import myModule

import inspect    
print inspect.getmembers(myModule, inspect.isclass)
```

Comment: thkan you .that's helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

You can import the module and scan all the names in it using dir (module):

```
import mymodule
import types


for item in dir(mymodule):
    itemtype = type(item)
    if itemtype == types.ClassType:
        print item + "is old style class"
    if itemtype == types.TypeType:
        print item + "is new style class"
```

Updated for old and new style classes

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use locale() function with filtering.